# Find the number of positive divisors of $N^2$ such that the positive divisors are less than N and do not divide N for $N=2^{17}*3^9*5^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-counting-function

Find the number of positive divisors of $N^2$ such that the positive divisors are less than N and do not divide N for $N=2^{17}*3^9*5^3$

My doubts
What I did firstly:-
$N^2=2^{34}*3^{18}*5^6$
Total number of factors will be $(34+1)(9+1)(3+1)=4655$

As given in the solution

There will be $(4655-1)/2=2327$ pairs of factors.

Why are we subtracting $1$ and why are we dividing it by $2$?

How these $2337$ factors of $N^2$ will be less than N?
Total number of factors will be $N=18*10*4=720$

So $720-1=719$ factors of N which are less than N and all of these will be a factors of $$N^2.

Why subtracting $1$ again from $720$?

I will be so glad if anyone of you can please clarify my doubts.

Comment: Factors come in pairs. If you have an odd number of factors, one will be the square root and the others will be in pairs $ab=N^2$. One of $a, b$ in each pair will be less than $N$ and one greater than $N$. There are some errors in arithmetic in your question - please check and edit.

Comment: There are more factors of $N^{2}$ than just the factors of $N$, even if you consider only factors less than $N$. For a quick example, $4$ is not a factor of $10$, but it is a factor of $10^{2}=100$.

Answer (score 2):

The reasonning step by step:

- You correctly found the total number of positive divisors of $N^2$: $4655$.
- One of these is $N$. Let's discard it. The other ones come in pairs whose products is $N^2$; there are $(4655-1)/2=2327$ such pairs.
- In each of these pairs one factor is above $N$ and one factor is below $N$. Hence the number is positive divisors of $N^2$ that are inferior to $N$ equals the number of pairs: $2327$

*edit: for clarification about these two steps, let's see what happens with $M=6$ instead of $N$. The positive divisors of $M^2=36$ are $1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36$. $M=6$ stands alone, and all the other ones can be regrouped in four pairs whose product is $M^2=36$: $1*36=2*18=3*12=4*9=36$. That's how we find the number of divisors of $M^2$ strictly inferior to $M$: one per pair, hence $(9-1)/2=4$.*

- Now we want to know how many of these do not divide $N$. The easiest way is to find the complement, which is exactly the number of positive divisors of $N$, since a divisor of $N$ is necessarily a divisor of $N^2$.
  There are $720$ divisors of $N$, one of them is $N$ itself so there are $719$ divisors of $N$ inferior to $N$.
- Finally, the solution is $2327-719=1608$

There are 1608 positive divisors of $N^2$ which are (strictly) smaller than $N$ and do not divise $N$.

Comment: I did not understand it. @Evargalo. Is there any easy approach?

Comment: Can you precise which part is blurry ? Until where can you understand ?

Comment: I understood till4665 pairs @Evargalo

Comment: WHy are we discarding N @Evargalo. Can you please justify with an example?

Comment: $N$ will not be a solution since it divises $N$, so it should not be discarded. Moreover it is the only one of the divisors of $N^2$ that doesn't form a pair since it has to be mutliplied by itself, and not by another divisor of $N^2$, to get $N^2$. That's the origin of the "$-1$"...

Comment: Please look at my edit, I hope it helps.